# Is it better to increase the number of worker threads or create my own thread pool in Netty?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

Let's assume our Netty server (4.1.32) responds HTTP calls. Let's further assume it must perform certain blocking actions before incoming requests can be answered, for example, it must perform an outgoing call (using a different library here) to load external data.

[Number of threads for NioEventLoopGroup with persistent connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074054/number-of-threads-for-nioeventloopgroup-with-persistent-connections) dicusses

> What happens if my messageReceived method blocks on something or takes a long time to complete?

which @Maksym responds with

> You should avoid using thread blocking actions in your handlers.

It's clear there is only a limited number of *worker threads*. So blocking all available worker threads effectively means Netty will queue any further requests, until worker threads become available.

On the other hand, moving blocking actions onto my own threads as suggested, will have performance impact for thread switching, and what will in turn be blocked by the available hardware is my own thread pool. IMHO using my own thread pool only adds another layer of complexity, but does not enhance performance. Instead, I'd rather increase the maximum number of worker threads and have Netty do the job of queuing requests.

What is the suggested practice here?

Comment: Ideally, you should not have any blocking code in your application.  If you want to handle many simultaneous actions, a huge pool of threads will cause you lots of performance problems in the long run and opens up the possibility of a catastrophic failure when you hit some theoretical limitation.

Comment: @JohnnyV at some point there will be a blocking operation in an application that needs DB read. you can do things asynchronously but IO is blocking at some point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use your own thread pool, period. The Netty worker threads are shared among many connections, if you block to handle one request it will hurt the others. The design assumes that your code returns quickly, if you need to block you must use a separate thread for that. The same applies if you need to perform a really expensive calculation, do it in another thread and return.

If you have done any Swing programming you can compare it to the GUI thread. If you block the GUI thread the user interface hangs and becomes unresponsive. Not good for a user interface and not for a high-performance networking application!

EDIT: just to be super clear, with classic IO one thread is typically assigned to a request and if the request blocks that is not the end of the world, if the thread pool is large enough other threads can process the other requests. With NIO you don't get a thread for your request, you get called by a thread that handles IO for many requests to process an event and you are supposed to do that as quickly as possible so that the thread can move on to the other requests. Blocking is really bad for the server.

Comment: what if worker thread is doing uses my own thread pool which is blocking (IO to database), this will lead to worker thread blocking too. I don't see at what point you will avoid blocking at all. It is either blocking at worker thread or my own thread. but if worker thread needs DB data which is fetched by my own thread, it is blocking anyway

Comment: Your worker thread must not wait for the blocking thread to complete. Netty calls event handlers. They are supposed to return quickly and they don't need to do everything before they return. If you can't handle a request quickly, return without writing the response. Then when the blocking thread is done and you have what you need write the response. The worker thread does not have to hang around waiting for that.

Comment: I don't understand when you say "return without writing the response". What happens from request-response point of view. A request comes in and I return without writing the response. when the blocking thread has finished processing the request, where it will write the response. The worker thread that handled the request has already completed with empty response rite.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. In Netty there is no one-to-one relation between the request and the worker thread. You have a channel where you can read and write data. You get called when there is something to read, so you can read the request. When you have read the complete request you can work on it, but if it is a long-running operation you don't need to use the thread that called you for reading. You can spin off a separate thread for the blocking operation and return. Then when you have a response, write it to the channel. Don't worry about the original thread.